# How do I fix the parse error in my membership ecommerce store built with BerryKids and woocommerce?

Tags: error-handling

I have an ecommerce store that is membership only. It was built using BerryKids theme (purchased) and WooCommerce. It was working up until a month ago when a client tried placing an order and received an error.

I got the email notification from WordPress about the error which seems to be due to a plugin. The plugin is deactivated but the certain elements on the site are still broken.

The error was this:

> Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.
>
> Fatal error: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` in /home/njofjdgf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpopal-themer/admin/class-project.php on line 157

I am stuck as I don't know how to fix this, my only thought is to start all over again but alot of hours have gone into putting the site up and products loaded. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to troubleshoot myself and went to line 157 but this is all it says.
 `<span class="<?php echo( $status['time_limit'] ? 'pass' : ( $data['time_limit'] >= 60 ) ? 'warning' : 'fail' ); ?>"></span>`

Comment: The "fatal error" spells it out in detail: what is not accepted (due to ambiguity, I suppose), and parenthesising either the first (*a* selects between two conditions *b* and *c* to select either *d* or *e*) or the second conditional expression (if *a*, then the result is *b*, else *c* decides between *d* and *e*).